# There's this card type in Yu-Gi-Oh that I can't quite put my finger on. It has to do with nature

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Back in ~6 grade there was a yu-gi-oh archetype that I really liked. I liked this because of the play-style and the art/character design in general, but I can't quite remember the name of the deck and/or monsters in 10th grade.

What I do remember though is that these cards are somewhat new, are themed around nature, not literal trees but from memory the people featured in these cards would wear leave-like clothing, kind-a anime/cutesy art style and would have many different cards with this "archetype" in the card name.

From memory, some of them in the card art would be riding flying beasts. Would anyone have the slightest idea what these cards would be?

Comment: What *year* was this (was it 4 years ago?). It will help us better find the answer (as we don't know what 6th grade was for you)

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear yet what year was this. From your post one can suppose you mean around 2015 (you said 6th grade and you imply you are now on 10th, so 4 years have passed).

*--If clarification is made I'll gladly update my answer--*

Assuming the cards are around 2015, and that are nature-ish themed, and some of them ride beasts, **I think you are talking about the [Ritual Beasts](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Ritual_Beast) Archetype**.

They were introduced mostly on the [Secrets of Eternity](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Secrets_of_Eternity) booster expansion, and on the [The Secret Forces](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Secret_Forces) expansion as well, which were launched on TCG January/February 2015, respectively.

Here some images of some cards of that Archetype to depict the theme they display (nature-ish, riding beasts, anime/cutesy, etc.):

[Ritual Beast Tamer Lara](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Ritual_Beast_Tamer_Lara):

[image]

[Ritual Beast Ulti-Gaiapelio](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Ritual_Beast_Ulti-Gaiapelio):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! This does fit all of my requirements and I have finally found it. The card archetype I was looking for is Daigusto!

Comment: As a comment, Ritual Beasts follow the Daigusto storyline in anime/manga